# Could not find the computed index field type: BXA.XA.Foundation.Custom.Search.AggregatedContent, BXA.XA.Foundation.Custom.Search

Tags: sxa, sxa-search, patch-configuration

I am trying to add links and extending the implementation of the `GetLayoutReferences` method from `Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.ComputedFields.AggregatedContent` class. However I am getting the following error:

```
Could not find the computed index field type: 
BXS.XA.Foundation.Custom.Search.AggregatedContent, BXS.XA.Foundation.Custom.Search
```

Here is my class code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Sitecore.Data.Fields;
using Sitecore.Data.Items;
using Sitecore.Layouts;
using Sitecore.Text;

namespace BXS.XA.Foundation.Custom.Search
{
    public class AggregatedContent : Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.ComputedFields.AggregatedContent
    {
        protected override IEnumerable<Item> GetLayoutReferences(Item item, ISet<Item> dataFolders)
        {
            LayoutField layoutField = new LayoutField(item);
            using (new ContextItemSwitcher(item))
            {
                DeviceItem[] all = item.Database.Resources.Devices.GetAll();
                foreach (DeviceItem device in all)
                {
                    IEnumerable<RenderingReference> references = layoutField.GetReferences(device);
                    foreach (RenderingReference item3 in references ?? Enumerable.Empty<RenderingReference>())
                    {
                        string[] items = new ListString(item3.Settings.DataSource ?? string.Empty).Items;
                        foreach (string path in items)
                        {
                            Item item2 = item.Database.GetItem(path, item.Language, Sitecore.Data.Version.Latest);
                            if (item2 != null && IsDataItem(item2, dataFolders))
                            {
                                // custom - start
                                if (item2.TemplateName == "Link List")
                                {
                                    foreach (Item linkItem in item2.Children)
                                    {
                                        var field = (LinkField)linkItem.Fields["Link"];
                                        if (field.IsInternal)
                                        {
                                            yield return field.TargetItem;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                // custom - end
                                yield return item2;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/" xmlns:search="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/search/">
  <sitecore>
    <contentSearch search:require="solr">
      <indexConfigurations>
        <defaultSolrIndexConfiguration>
          <documentOptions>
            <fields hint="raw:AddComputedIndexField">
              <field fieldName="sxacontent">
                <patch:delete />
              </field>
              <field fieldName="sxacontent" returnType="textCollection" type="BXS.XA.Foundation.Custom.Search.AggregatedContent, BXS.XA.Foundation.Custom.Search">
                <mediaIndexing ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultSolrIndexConfiguration/mediaIndexing"/>
              </field>
            </fields>
          </documentOptions>
        </defaultSolrIndexConfiguration>
      </indexConfigurations>
    </contentSearch>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Comment: What you will need to try is change your project namespace to something different so it does not collide with SXA names. You could try Olivia.XA.Foundation and then update the patch to match the new namespace and library.

Comment: you have to register the assembly like this
your method for computed field, your dll

Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Custom.Search.AggregatedContent, Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Custom

Comment: @MichaelWest I just changed it and am still receiving the same error.  I updated my code above.

Comment: "BXS.XA.Foundation.Custom.Search" - Is it the name of your DLL? If not change the part after "," to name of your DLL "BXS.XA.Foundation.Custom.Search.AggregatedContent, BXS.XA.Foundation.Custom.Search" @OliviaShettles

Comment: @VadimBirkos that was it.  Thank you!

Comment: @OliviaShettles You are welcome! Added response for this question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can assume that the Assemble Name part in

```
"BXS.XA.Foundation.Custom.Search.AggregatedContent, BXS.XA.Foundation.Custom.Search"
```

does not exist in your solution.

Please, check that your Assemble Name is correct. It has to have next format:

`{ClassNamespace}.{ClassName}, {AssembleName}`